# Async Behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The following function -

```
a = [1,2,3];
function f() {
    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        setTimeout(() => console.log(i),3000)
    }
}
```

gives me output - 0,1,2 which is as expected.

However, the following function -

```
function f() {
    for(var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
        setTimeout((function(el){console.log(el)})(i),3000)
    }
}
```

gives the following output - 
`0` and throws following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__wrapper_2__' of undefined
```

However, in the last function if I remove setTimeout, I am getting expected behavior i.e. -

```
function f() {
    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){ (function(i){console.log(i)})(i);
    }
}
```

I am getting the expected output - 0,1,2
So, Why setTimeout is giving me error with when defining new function, but not with arrow functions ?

Comment: I don't see any error for second snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to call the function in the argument list. It doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't:

```
function f() {
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(console.log(i), 3000);
    }
}
f();
```

The first argument of setTimeout is an uncalled function, like:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000);
```

or

```
const method = () => console.log(i);
setTimeout(method, 1000)
```

Edit: Also,

```
function f() {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            (function (el) {
                console.log(el);
            })(i);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
let a = [1, 2, 3];
f();
```

Will return 3, 3, 3 because after 3000ms the given function will be called with the global variable i as a parameter, and at that point i === 3;

However, in the following example, the value of i at the time is saved in the function. I believe that has something to do with closures, maybe someone else can follow up with a better explanation of that.

```
function f() {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i);
        }, 3000);
    }
}
let a = [1, 2, 3];
f();
```